# How do I convert an field ID to actual text from another field name in another table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

How do I convert an ID field in one table to an actual first and last name from another table?  I need to select the f.approving_cm(which is an ID from the event_admission table) and convert this to the name(ccms_user_first_name and ccms_user_last_name) of the ID from the ccms_all_users table.  Here is my query below:

```
Select *
From openquery(ccms_rpt,
'
select f.member_id, f.approving_cm, a.ccms_user_first_name, a.ccms_user_last_name
from ccmsdba_txc_prd.event_admission f 
inner join ccmsdba_txc_prd.ccms_all_users a on f.approving_cm = a.ccms_id
'
)
```

Comment: Your query looks reasonable.  What is your problem?

Comment: I am not for sure how to convert for example f.approving_cm = 171 to ccms_user_first_name + ccms_user_last_name, the actual text.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Your query returns the first and last names in separate columns.  Isn't that good enough?

Comment: I guess I am not explaining it good, my apologies.  How would I convert the f.approving_cm (which is an ID) to text?

Comment: I think where Gordon is being thrown is that the query is returning the results you're looking for, so he doesn't see an issue. Are you looking more for a single use function that returns a first and last name when you pass an ID to it? If that's the case, please tag your question with the dialect of SQL (i.e. tsql, msaccess, plsql, etc..) so you can get the correct syntax for your DBMS.

Comment: Yes you are correct Jaaz Cole.  I didnt think to put the correct tag.  But you are correct, I am looking to return a first and last name when I pass an ID to it.  And I am using Transact SQL

Comment: @NathanielRollinsJr. Right now, your query returns all the IDs (f.approving_cm) with all corresponding first and last names. Am I right in thinking that you need to get only a single first and last name in your result set? Can you give a sample output that you are looking for? This will better help understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: It won't let me post an example unless I have a 10 reputation.  Sorry guys I am learning SQL to prepare for my next job as analyst.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getCCMSuserName (@ccms_id INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN (
    SELECT a.ccms_user_first_name + ' ' + a.ccms_user_last_name
    FROM ccmsdba_txc_prd.ccms_all_users a
    WHERE a.ccms_id = @ccms_id
)
END
```

Comment: You haven't concatenated the columns.

Comment: +1 for a reasonable attempt to provide an answer (that is correct) to the question.

Comment: Thanks!  How do I concatenate the columns to get the output desired?

Comment: The plus sign, and any character constant, as seen above. I edited my post to return "FirstName LastName". You'll need to use explicit casts to VARCHAR/NVARCHAR if you try to concatenate a numerical value to a VARCHAR or NVARCHAR value.